# htaccess help to rename directory

Tags: .htaccess, rename, directory

I have 2 directories that I would like to rename without losing my search ranking. Here is the url convention and suggested name change:

Old: mysitename.com/folder1/folder2/filenames

to

New: mysitename.com/newfoldername1/newfoldername2/filenames

filename is the given name of each page

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the rules that you have tried and are having trouble with.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/folder1/folder2/(.*)$ $1/newfoldername1/newfoldername2/$2 [R,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/folder1/folder2/(.*)$ $1/newfoldername1/newfoldername2/$2 [R,L]`

The problem with this rule is that RewriteRules only match on the path, not the domain. You have the `(.*)/` at the front of the rule as if you are trying to match the domain, which isn't necessary. You have also set it as a redirect rather than a rewrite ... maybe this is what you want, in which case keep the "R" flag as you had it, but I'll remove it in the code below in case you just want to rewrite. Modify the rule as follows and it should work:

`RewriteRule ^newfoldername1/newfoldername2/(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/$1`

Edit: Now that you've posted your other rules, I removed the `[L]` and reversed the order to what I think you're trying to do.

Edit 2: The above rule assumed that you wanted a user entering `domain.com/newfoldername1/newfoldername2/whatever` to be silently rewritten to `domain.com/folder1/folder2/whatever`. The phrasing of your latest comment indicates that instead you want a user entering `domain.com/folder1/folder2/whatever` to be redirected (in other words, to have the address change in their browser) to `domain.com/newfoldername1/newfoldername2/whatever` and that the server is ready to process this new path. In that case, the following rule is required:

`RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2(/.*)?$ /newfoldername1/newfoldername2$1` [R=301,L]

Comment: This is the complete file: 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^questions/question/(.*)$ /augusta/ga/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress



Still not working

Comment: I just added that to your question (pending approval) ... you should add details like that into the question where they are much easier to read.

Comment: When you say "This is the complete file" ... I don't see the rule I provided. Where did you put it that you say it isn't working? Rule order is very important. That rule I provided must go above the other rules. Also, now that I see the rest of the rules, I've edited my answer to omit the "`[L]`" which would block the subsequent rules.

Comment: RewriteRule ^augusta/ga/(.*)$ /questions/question/$1
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: The new rule is at the top but it still does not work. I also tried adding it between each rule with no luck. Also please answer this: your rule has the new folder names at the front and the old names at the rear. Is that what was intended to make it work?

Comment: The way the rule is written right now, with the new folder names first means that if a user enters the URL `mysitename.com/newfoldername1/newfoldername2/filenames` in their browser, they will be served the page `mysitename.com/folder1/folder2/filenames` without the URL changing in their browser. This is the kind of rule most people ask for with a CMS. If you are looking for something different, please update your question to list (1)the URL the user should enter, (2)the URL that will actually be served, and (3)if you want the URL to be updated in the user's browser (redirect) or not (rewrite).

Comment: I have no preference. Just as long as the old folders redirect to the new folders. But for now, it did not work for me.

Comment: Updated again per latest comment.